# Copying 3B rows in SQL Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to copy a table, which has about 3B rows in same database with NO TEXT/NTEXT or other LOB Columns. What are the fastest ways to do to minimize downtime? I have tried bcp, import/export and SELECT INTO. I gathered time statistics for each and it requires at least 10 hour down time. We are on the fastest SAN (compllent SC800 full of write/read intensive SSDs).

Comment: Why do you need downtime,even if you have new rows or changed rows, you could cater to them finally after inserting all data.

Comment: if it is seperate server,i would recommend taking a backup and doing a restore and then do a insert,so to avoid network latency

Comment: what version of sql server are you using ? [Use BCP OUT and BULK INSERT to insert data.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/55063/8783) will help  you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new table, bulk load import using batched transactions of say 100,000 rows per load, then add indexes if necessary, drop/rename existing table and rename new table to production. That's the process I've developed and followed for such large SQL tables.

Comment: Thats Garren, thats the plan already in place. I was hoping for something that I may be missing. 3rd party  tool etc ?

Comment: If you follow Garren's suggestion it should not take 10 hours. How many columns/length of columns are there that you are importing? I have done many imports of 3B rows (and larger) and when I was importing into new tables that did not have indexes or triggers the import was much faster then ten hours.

Comment: Grasping at straws, but you may be able to load files concurrently faster than in serial, namely to multiple separate tables simultaneously. But if all the data must be in the same table ultimately, that likely won't help much if at all. What kind of performance are you getting with your current setup, # of columns, and batch size?