# MySQL: Alternatives to BigDump for Importing Huge Files

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import a 40GB .sql file into a fresh MySQL database. Are there any alternatives to BigDump?  The connection timed out on BigDump after about 30 minutes. Ideally, I could find a solution that had some type of progress bar as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Split the 1 file into N lines (generally I recommend 100,000) which will create (Total lines in file/N) files.

2) Create a new table without indexes.

3) Run a for loop bash script to load each file in separately in its own transaction.

4) Add indexes if necessary

5) Drop/rename existing table you're trying to replace and rename new table to production (if necessary).

This option is helpful for a multitude of reasons, namely it can help find problems (such as unexpected skipped rows) quickly, enables quick insight into the validity of the load, and chunks up the load so as to avoid a massive single transaction and thus point of failure.

I've never used BigDump, but I would surmise it does something similar.

A similar Q&A: [Copying 3B rows in SQL Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43719888/copying-3b-rows-in-sql-table/43719936#43719936)